# Can't display an image in react from backend django

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I want to display an image which I got the src from in the database linked to django on localhost 8000, in react (localhost 3000).

here is my view:

```
class NextQuestion(APIView):    
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'old_questions'

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        old_questions = request.data.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)

        if len(old_questions):
            old_questions_q = [Q(id=x) for x in old_questions]        
            questions_valides = Question.objects.exclude(reduce(operator.or_, old_questions_q))
            if len(questions_valides) == 0 :
                return Response("Il n'y a plus de questions disponibles!")
        else:
            questions_valides = Question.objects.all()
        
        index = randint(0, len(questions_valides) -1)
        new_question = QuestionSerializer(questions_valides[index]).data

        return Response(new_question)
```

My serializer:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'
```

My urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    ######
    path('quiz/', include('quiz.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And in my settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In my .js:

```
<Fade in={!toggle} {...(!toggle ? { timeout: 2000 } : {})}>
    <Paper elevation={0} className={classes.paper}>
        <img className={classes.image} src={image} alt="La réponse." />
    </Paper>
</Fade >
```

My app component:

```
const App = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={5} >
            <Router>
                <Switch>                
                    <NavLayout>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                        <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} />
                        <Route exact path='/reset-password' component={ResetPassword} />
                        <Route exact path='/password/reset/confirm/:uid/:token' component={ResetPasswordConfirm} />
                        <Route exact path='/activate/:uid/:token' component={Activate} />
                    </NavLayout>                
                </Switch> 
            </Router>
        </SnackbarProvider>        
    </Provider>    
);

export default App;
```

The request return status 200, but the response is empty:

```
GET
    
scheme
    http
host
    127.0.0.1:8000
filename
    /media/images/quiz/cochon.png
Adresse
    127.0.0.1:8000
État200
OK
VersionHTTP/1.1
Transfert2,42 Ko (taille 2,17 Ko)
Politique de référentsame-origin

    
Content-Length
    2227
Content-Type
    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date
    Sun, 18 Apr 2021 08:18:28 GMT
Referrer-Policy
    same-origin
Server
    WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.9.2
Vary
    Origin
X-Content-Type-Options
    nosniff
X-Frame-Options
    DENY
    
Accept
    image/webp,*/*
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate
Accept-Language
    fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control
    max-age=0
Connection
    keep-alive
Cookie
    csrftoken=8e5HTXPQRNuesBbAC389HePJYYebgcKNS7Km60kP6uqURbIpNyA3khuuJPQK4V7M; djdt=hide; sessionid=ffneb7uu8ia5ly8f7w45a2ynbemz6886; PGADMIN_INT_KEY=7bde6f56-0a71-41e0-9953-f719d7135568; PGADMIN_LANGUAGE=en; tabstyle=html-tab
Host
    127.0.0.1:8000
Referer
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0
```

My variable image has this value: `/media/images/quiz/animal-2029280_1280.png`

It should match the path corresponding to the image, yet it doesn't load. Did I forget a manipulation? Or a parameter error? I only have a problem with the image, the rest is fine.

I have the same result if i run my app on localhost 8000 or 3000.

Thx!

Comment: If i try in my navigator: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/quiz/animal-2029280_1280.png`, i got nothing. my image is in this path on my computer: `C:\Users\nicou\Desktop\lpdm\backend\media\images\quiz\animal-2029280_1280.png`

Comment: My get has status 200 but the response is empty, it doesn't load. I did add my app component, perhaps my react router could be a problem? If I try the path in the url, I only see my layout.

Comment: Maybe the regex `r'^.*'` is catching all requests, also images. Did you try to exclude `media` urls from regex?

Comment: You are right! if i delete this line, the image url is working. Thx a lot for your help, you saved my day :) i ll try to exclude media, i don't really know how to do that...

Comment: I did re_path(r'^.*(?!(media))', it seems to work correctly. Thank you again!

Comment: @daniherrera Thanks a lot made my day I was struggling with it for days your one line made my day

Comment: @AbhinavBanerjee : Nice! Glad to hear that!  [What is the best way to say "Thank you" to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294902/what-is-the-best-way-to-say-thank-you-to-stack-overflow) Check my answer below ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in this two lines of code:

```
urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The first url path regular expression pattern **is matching all urls**. Because of this, the second one has no effect.

To solve it, just change order to these two lines (or modify regex to don't match media urls)